# Ionic iOS Cordova Switching between apps stays old icon, new icon is not being generated app switcher

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, resources, icons

Currently I am facing a strange issue with iOS Resources for ICON when switching between apps.

The app that I am currently working is a template downloaded from codecanyon, and I have changed the icon.png and splash.png to the client logo.

Everywhere else the Icon is working as it should, only when switching between apps, the screen where you swipe between apps, the small icon on the top left is not changed and it stays as it is.

What I am seeing right now is that when I generate icons with cordova-res, it generates 28 icons, these 3 icons are not being generated by cordova and i had to make them manually:

```
<icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
<icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
<icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
```

I did generate them manually and put them on the resources/ios/icon location but still no success.

I also looked up on XCODE, the old icon is not there at all.

This is the ICON that is working on the home screen.

[image: This is the ICON that is working on the home screen.]

This is the old icon that is appearing on the top left.

[image: This is the old icon that is appearing on the top left.]

IONIC INFO:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (/Users/leotrinelmazi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.29
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 1.2.1

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.11.3
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.19.0 (/Users/leotrinelmazi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.8
   OS         : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode      : Xcode 13.1 Build version 13A1030d
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was already making this question, I was also looking around stackoverflow and ended up on some suggestions.

The solution for me was to uninstall the app (which have done multipletimes), shut down-turn on the iPhone (or restart) install the app again.

Now the icon is showing as it should.